# Use app engine yaml parser in scripts

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yaml

I have some configuration files I want to write in yaml and read in a Python script running on Google app engine. Given that app engine uses app.yaml, index.yaml among others it seems reasonable to assume there is a python yaml parser available.

1. How can I gain access to this parser (what is the import) and where can I find its documentation.
2. I'd also like to use this parser for scripts running outside of agg engine (build scripts and such) so how can I gain access to the same import from a script that will run from the command line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The YAML library is included with the AppEngine SDK. It is located in google_appengine/lib/yaml. You should be able to use it in your AppEngine code just by having `import yaml` in your code.

For non-AppEngine work, a quick Google search reveals http://pyyaml.org/ home to many and various Python implementations.

Comment: I know I can download and install a yaml library for Python but I'd prefer to use the same one that is included with app engine for consistency. I wouldn't mind reading documentation for Google's version either although I suppose I can dive into the code if necessary. EDIT: python setup.py install on the lib in the google_appengine/lib/yaml directory installed it for me. That will do.

Comment: @James: if you look in the directory where the YAML library is located in the AppEngine SDK, you'll see the README file. It explains that it is the PyYAML version, and it contain a command line that you can use to install the version that is included right there as part of your general Python installation.