# Parse YAML file in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, yaml

I'm trying to parse a YAML file within Google Apps Script. I would like to use the information from a YAML file in Google Sheets.

From what I understood, the underlying library is available ([Use app engine yaml parser in scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093080/use-app-engine-yaml-parser-in-scripts)) but I don't seem to understand how I can use this library.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [so]. AFAIK libraries are intended to be used with specific programming languages. The question that you linked is about scripts written in Python but Google Apps Script uses JavaScript. Keep searching / learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it can depend on how complicated is your yaml. For simply cases you can use this lib https://code.google.com/archive/p/javascript-yaml-parser/downloads

Just download and unpack the latest .gz file and copy contents of the file `yaml.js` into your project:

[image]

Then you can convert your yaml string into a json object this way:

```
// your YAML sting

var string =
`foo: bar
stuff:
  foo: bar
  bar: foo
arr:
  - aaa
  - bbb
  - ccc
`

// JSON object

var obj = YAML.eval(string);

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Output:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "stuff": {
    "foo": "bar",
    "bar": "foo"
  },
  "arr": ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
}
```

Comment: The similar (but not quite) question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67898452/convert-google-spreadsheet-structure-to-dictionary

Comment: Thanks! This was the route that I went with and it worked out perfectly.