# How to use a external Javascript library (PDF lib) in Apps script?

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, libraries, pdf.js, pdflib

I need to modifie a PDF on a Apps script application. To do that I want to use a JS library : [PDF-LIB](https://pdf-lib.js.org/)

my code :

```
eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://unpkg.com/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.js").getContentText());

function modifyPdf() {
  const url = 'https://pdf-lib.js.org/assets/with_update_sections.pdf'
  const existingPdfBytes = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();

  const pdfDoc = PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes)
  const helveticaFont = pdfDoc.embedFont(StandardFonts.Helvetica)

  const pages = pdfDoc.getPages()
  const firstPage = pages[0]
  const { width, height } = firstPage.getSize()
  firstPage.drawText('This text was added with JavaScript!', {
    x: 5,
    y: height / 2 + 300,
    size: 50,
    font: helveticaFont,
    color: rgb(0.95, 0.1, 0.1),
    rotate: degrees(-45),
  })

  const pdfBytes = pdfDoc.save()
}
```

When I execute the fonction `modifyPDF` I have :

```
Erreur  
ReferenceError: PDFDocument is not defined
modifyPdf   @ modifie_pdf.gs:7
```

Do you know how I can import the js lib on my Apps script application ?

Comment: You can download the pdf-lib.js as a file. And paste its contents into your code. Something like here (external lib to parse YAML): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71327482/parse-yaml-file-in-google-apps-script/

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. It can't find PDFDocument again

Comment: Technically you can include a library into your project this way. If the code from this library doesn't work it is another matter. It's quite likely that the code can't do on Google servers the same things as in the local browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The `eval`uated global variable namespace is `PDFLib`. So, all variables like `rgb`, `degrees`, `PDFDocument` are keys of this  object and should be referenced as such.
- Most functions present in the library use `promises`, which, although is not supported by apps script functionally, it is supported syntactically. Therefore, `async`, `await` should be used, else you'll only get `promise` objects and not the actual `document` or `font`
- The library uses `setTimeout`, which is not available in apps script. I used `Utilities.sleep` to simulate it's behavior.
- `getContentText()` returns `text` and not `binary content`. Use `getContent()` to get `byte[]` instead and cast it to `Uint8Array`

```
eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://unpkg.com/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.js").getContentText());
/*+++simulate setTimeout*/setTimeout = (func, sleep) => (Utilities.sleep(sleep),func())

async function modifyPdf() {
  const url = 'https://pdf-lib.js.org/assets/with_update_sections.pdf'
  const existingPdfBytes = new /*cast to uint8*/Uint8Array(/*returns byte[]*/UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContent/*---Text*/());
  /*+++ simulate import*/const { PDFDocument, StandardFonts, rgb, degrees} = PDFLib;
  const pdfDoc = /*+++*/await PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes)
  const helveticaFont = /*+++*/ await pdfDoc.embedFont(StandardFonts.Helvetica)

  const pages = pdfDoc.getPages()
  const firstPage = pages[0]
  const { width, height } = firstPage.getSize()
  firstPage.drawText(`This text was added with JavaScript\n\n${' '.repeat(10)}(Google Apps script)!`, {
    x: width/10 + 60,
    y: height/10 + 120,
    size: 40,
    font: helveticaFont,
    color: rgb(0.1, 0.1, 0.1),
    rotate: degrees(50),
    opacity: 0.5,
  })

  const pdfBytes = /*+++*/await pdfDoc.save();
  /*+++*/DriveApp.createFile(Utilities.newBlob(pdfBytes).setName('newpdf from apps script'))
}
```