# How do I use eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch()) to load external javascript in my google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, libraries, aws-sdk-js

I am trying to send an email from a Google Apps Script function (using Amazon SES Javascript SDK) using the below code -

```
function sendemail(email,name,code,date,expiry,version) {
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1206.0.min.js").getContentText());

  const configure = {
      accessKeyId: "<mykeyid>",
      secretAccessKey: "<myaccesskey>",
      apiVersion: '2010-12-01',
      region: 'us-east-1'
  };
  
  const ses = new AWS.SES(configure); //AWS is not defined error

  //... rest of code
}
```

Now when I run the `sendemail()` function, it says "AWS is not defined" - which means clearly there is something wrong with the way I am referencing the external file, hence its not able to find AWS. What am I doing wrong? I know it might sound like a silly question, but I am a beginner with JS hence a bit confused on what is wrong... please guide... Thanks! :)

Comment: Try `var self=globalThis` before `eval`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the external script executes, the loaded  `AWS` global object may not be properly exported. In this case, the script tests whether `self`(as well as `window` and `module`) is available and exports itself there. The global object in apps script can be referenced by [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis). So adding,

```
const self = globalThis;
```

would help export `AWS` object on to `globalThis`. It's also preferable that you also use [indirect `eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) and not direct `eval`. Therefore `eval` should be outside any function and that prevents the script from accessing your local variables. You may also [overload global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73467157/) using proxies to avoid the script from accessing privileged data.

Even after all this, the script might require certain objects only available in browser like `setTimeout`. You may need to emulate those object's behavior using functionality already present in apps script.  For  example, [`setTimeout` may be emulated using `Utilities.sleep`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73166361/how-to-use-a-external-javascript-library-pdf-lib-in-apps-script). It's a step by step manual process of figuring out all the "missing" dependencies and emulating each one of them.