I want to add text to a pdf. Is there any solution in Apps Script?
My name is Andreea. I'm a beginner in Apps Script and I want to edit a pdf by adding text. Is there any solution? I don't really know how to use the codes and an easy to understand explanation would be helpful. I've tried some codes from the Internet but no success
Thanks!

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73166361/
